# Android : How can I use DX option in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, jython

I simply thought I could use jython for developing Android App.
But it was not easier than I thought.
I created android sample project and added jython.jar into the project.
After soon I encountered with "Conversion to Dalvik format failed" error msg.
So I googled almost every pages about that msg.
However I could not find a proper answer.
Closest answer was using "--no-locals" in dx option.
I did it in command console and it seemed to work well. I guess...

My question is...
I want to use the dx option("--no-locals") with eclipse.
Because eclipse automatically copys apk file to the emulator and runs it.
Is it anyway to set dx.bat option ("--no-locals") in eclipse?
Is there anyone who succeed in use of jython for android?

Comment: If you just want to use the Python language to write an Android app, perhaps you should look into this: http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/

Comment: Thank you. I had checked it before I thought of jython. But It didn't look like supporting all APIs in android. So I thought it would be better to use jython. Does android-scripting provide all APIs in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I don't know about jython.jar specifically, but it is not given that it is even possible to add every externaljar file to an Android project. It might very well be that your jar is depending on packages that are not included in the Android SDK (because Android isn't an exact clone of Java, just to have mentioned that), and if so it won't be possible to include it.

Try looking very closely on the error stack trace and look for anything indicating there are some missing dependencies. This might give you a clue if this is the case for your jar.